# How can I print something based on the result of a boolean method?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

I have two methods

```
*`public boolean validateMarks() {
    return (this.qualifyingMarks >= 65 && this.qualifyingMarks <= 100);
    }   
    public boolean validateCourseId() {
    return (this.courseId >= 1001 && this.courseId <= 1005);
    }`*
```

validateMarks(): Used to validate qualifying exam marks - qualifying marks is in the range of 65 to 100(both inclusive)
validateCourseId(): Used to validate the course entered, based on the courseId - given in the table above
calculateCourseFee(): Used to calculate the course fee after applying the discount.

So when is less than 65 print print "not elegible, you've failed" and when the course is not valid "course is not correct, please try again with the correct number of the course"

and this is my calculateCourseFee method

```
***if(this.validateMarks()) {
            this.courseFee = fee - (fee * discount);
            
            System.out.println("****Course Allocation Details****" + "\n" +
                    "Student Name: " + this.getStudentName() + "\n" + 
                    "Course Id: " + this.getCourseId() + "\n" +
                    "Qualifying Exam Marks: " + this.getQualifyingMarks() + "\n" +
                    "Student's Registration Id: " + this.getRegistrationId() + "\n" +
                    "Total Course Fee: " + this.getCourseFee() + "\n" +
                    "Hostel Required: " + hostel);
        }else {
            System.out.println("wrong for marks ");
        }
        
        if(this.validateCourseId()) {
            this.courseFee = fee - (fee * discount);
            
            System.out.println("****Course Allocation Details****" + "\n" +
                    "Student Name: " + this.getStudentName() + "\n" + 
                    "Course Id: " + this.getCourseId() + "\n" +
                    "Qualifying Exam Marks: " + this.getQualifyingMarks() + "\n" +
                    "Student's Registration Id: " + this.getRegistrationId() + "\n" +
                    "Total Course Fee: " + this.getCourseFee() + "\n" +
                    "Hostel Required: " + hostel);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Wroog for course");
        }
        ***

I make two different ifs for the two requirements, but everytime I run it, it prints the else statement to, even if marks is greather than 65... am I missing something?

Reviewing my code and tell me what am I missing or what am I doing wrong
```

Comment: add `System.out.println(this.qualifyingMarks);` to your `validateMarks` method to undertake basic debugging

Answer (score 0):

The portion of the code you have shown here seems to be working as expected.

```
public class Driver {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Eligible e1 = new Eligible();
    e1.calculateCourseFee();
  }
}

class Eligible{
int qualifyingMarks = 66;
int courseId = 1002;

public boolean validateMarks() {
    return (this.qualifyingMarks >= 65 && this.qualifyingMarks <= 100);
    }   

public boolean validateCourseId() {
    return (this.courseId >= 1001 && this.courseId <= 1005);
    }

public void calculateCourseFee(){
    if(this.validateMarks()) {
        System.out.println("works for marks");
    }else {
        System.out.println("wrong for marks ");
    }
    
    if(this.validateCourseId()) {
        System.out.println("works for course");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Wroog for course");
    }
  }
}
```

output:

> works for marks 
> works for course

Maybe the issues is with how you set the values for the `qualifyingMarks` and `courseId` variables?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could give you a like or thumbs up, I finally did it, thanks to all of your answers you gave me, and I just combined the two ifs into one. here's the code:

```
if(this.validateCourseId() && this.validateMarks()) {
             this.courseFee = fee - (fee * discount);
                
                System.out.println("****Course Allocation Details****" + "\n" +
                        "Student Name: " + this.getStudentName() + "\n" + 
                        "Course Id: " + this.getCourseId() + "\n" +
                        "Qualifying Exam Marks: " + this.getQualifyingMarks() + "\n" +
                        "Student's Registration Id: " + this.getRegistrationId() + "\n" +
                        "Total Course Fee: " + this.getCourseFee() + "\n" +
                       "Hostel Required: " + hostel);
        }else if(!this.validateCourseId()) {
            System.out.println("Wrong course");
        }
        else if(!this.validateMarks()) {
            System.out.println("You've failed");
        }
```

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score -1):

maybe qualifyingMarks is zero or another value, print qualifyingMarks in method "validateMarks",u will get the reason of your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).